# How to make a string equal another string

Tags: excel, vba, string

Probably a simple question. I cant seem to find the answer though.

I am trying to make a string equal to another string but I cant seem to get it to work. No VBA errors. It just skips this line.  The line I am referring to is `USRInVenName = VenName`. 
Instead, to make this work I need to put in `Sheets("Log").Range("D4") = VenName`. I rather make the string = string.

```
Sub TGHL()

Dim VenName As String
Dim USRInVenName As String

VenName = Sheets("Log").Range("i4")
USRInVenName = Sheets("Log").Range("D4")

   If VenName <> USRInVenName Then

        Dim VendCopyOver As Integer

        VendCopyOver = MsgBox("Copy over name?", _
                               vbYesNo, "Name Correction")

        If VendCopyOver = vbYes Then
        USRInVenName = VenName

        End If

    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you thinking that the variable is somehow permanently linked to the cell? because Excel doesnt work like that.

Comment: @braX this is more about basic programming than it is about Excel though. Excel doesn't care in the slightest what variables VBA uses ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? This will use 2 variables that are set to the Cells, so they don't contains the value of the cells, they *are* representing the cells. When you write `VenName`, you are in fact using `VenName.Value` - that is called the *default property*. When assigning the value from one Range variable to the other, you are assigning the value directly into the cell.

```
Sub TGHL()

    Dim VenName As Range
    Dim USRInVenName As Range
    Set VenName = Sheets("Log").Range("i4")
    Set USRInVenName = Sheets("Log").Range("D4")

    If VenName <> USRInVenName Then   ' VenName.Value <> USRInVenName.Value
        If MsgBox("Copy over name?", vbYesNo, "Name Correction") = vbYes Then
            USRInVenName = VenName    ' USRInVenName.Value = VenName.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```